# How to write $i^i$ as $x+iy$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

From Euler I see that:

$i^i = e^{-\pi/2}$

Then can I just write it as: 
$$
\cos{(-\pi/2)} + i\sin{(-\pi/2)}?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Note that 
$$
i = e^{i\pi/2},
$$
and therefore
$$
i^i =e^{-\pi/2} = e^{-\pi/2} + 0i.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \neq \cos(-\frac{\pi}{2}) + i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{2})$

There is no $i$ coefficient in the exponent of $e$

Answer (score 1):

$e^{-\pi/2}$ is real number. So, it will be written as $e^{-\pi/2} + 0i$, only imaginary numbers of the form $e^{i\theta}$ can be written as $\cos {\theta}+i\sin {\theta}$