# Expressing $i^{i - 3}$ in the form $a + ib$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

In expressing $i^{i - 3}$ in the form $a + ib$ I have gone as far as simplifying this to

$-i^{i + 1}$

but I'm not sure where to go from here. Are there any hints you can give me that I'm missing out?

Comment: Hint: $a^{m+n} = a^m\times a^n$. Or perhaps a better hint is to use the exponential representation for complex numbers.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg I've broken it down to that but I still can't see where that leads to. Unless this means that a = 0 and b = -i^i? But I found that an unusual answer

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2191338/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/191572/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810925/42969

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the expression using the hint given in comment by  *ÍgjøgnumMeg*:
$$i^{i-3} = i^i\cdot i^{-3} = i\cdot i^{i}$$

Now in *principle argument* of $i$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore $i = e^{i \pi/2}$. Substitute and you get the value: $0+i  e^{-\pi / 2}$